How to define a function with the return type defined by the arg value?
I am trying to build a generic function that performs the type-dependent symbol lookup.
The shortened version of the example is as follows:
type Symbol = TypeDef | VarDecl
interface TypeDef
{
  kind: 'type',
  name: string,
  typeData: string;
}
interface VarDecl
{
  kind: 'var',
  name: string,
  varData: number
}
type SymbolKind = Symbol['kind'];

interface SymbolMap
{
  type: TypeDef[],
  var: VarDecl[]
}

Now I need a generic type-safe symbol lookup function.
If I make SymbolKind the function argument, then I can't narrow down the function result type:
function LookupSymbol(kind: SymbolKind, map: SymbolMap, name: string)
{
   let symbols = map[kind];
   for(var symbol of symbols)
   {
     if(symbol.name == name)
        return symbol;
   }
}

let x = LookupSymbol('var', m, 'x'); // x: TypeDef | VarDecl | undefined

If I make the symbol type a generic argument, then I can't select the map property:
interface SymbolBase
{
  kind: SymbolKind,
  name: string
}

function LookupSymbol2<T extends SymbolBase>(map: SymbolMap, name: string): T | undefined
{
   let symbols = map[???];
   for(var symbol of symbols)
   {
     if(symbol.name == name)
        return symbol;
   }
   return undefined;
}

Is there a way to write down this in TypeScript, so I can get either a
LookupSymbol<VarDecl>(SymbolMap map, string name): VarDecl | undefined
or
LookupSymbol(SymbolMap map, 'var', string name): VarDecl | undefined
?
Tried to use Extract<> generic type as the function return type in option 1 - doesn't work, as it needs a type or const, instead of a parameter.
Tried to extract the kind from the generic type parameter - but couldn't find a way to do it.

Take a look at function overloading.
In your case, you could define the following overloads:
function LookupSymbol(kind: 'var', map: SymbolMap, name: string): VarDecl | undefined;
function LookupSymbol(kind: 'type', map: SymbolMap, name: string): TypeDef | undefined;
function LookupSymbol(kind: SymbolKind, map: SymbolMap, name: string)
{
   // ...
}


Thanks, this does work. Is there a way to "auto-generate" these overloads from the type definition? Real case does have a bit more options in the Symbol type. I don't want to repeat the type list in two places

This took a bit of asking around, but it turns out you can. I hope you don't mind that I simplified the example a bit: link (pastebin because ts playground is too long).
